# Forest trees fitting on page

Tags: trees, forest

My forest looks like this but it does not fit on a page, this is my first time using this package. I am looking for suggestions to fit this into a page, hopefully they will not be too intensive because I plan on making an even bigger tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw, l sep=20pt}
 [1,red 
[2, edge label={node[midway,left] {A}}
  [1,red,edge label={node[midway,left] {B}} 
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
        ] 
  [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
            ]
        [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            ]
]
[2, edge label={node[midway,left] {B}}
  [1,red, edge label={node[midway,left] {A}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
            ] 
  [1,red, edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
        ]
        [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
        ]
]
    [2, edge label={node[midway,left] {C}}  
  [1,red,edge label={node[midway,left] {A}} 
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
        ] 
  [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}} 
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}]
        ]
        [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {D}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}]
            ]
]
    [2, edge label={node[midway,left] {D}}
  [1,red,edge label={node[midway,left] {A}} 
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            ] 
  [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}]
            ]
        [1,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {C}}
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}]
            [2,red,edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}]
            ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code to make a compilable document. There are various options here, but without knowing how large your pages are, it is impossible to give a meaningful answer other than scale-the-tree-to-fit which is a solution to be avoided if at all possible. (I sometimes use it with Beamer, but it is not a good option at all.) Also, it would help to know what kind of solution would work. Since we don't know what the tree is about, we don't know if, for example, it is essential to keep nodes on a single level aligned or not.

Comment: I've completed the code. The tree will pretty much always be symmetric though I don't really mind if it appears asymmetric for fitting purposes.

Comment: Hi, if anybody is still looking at this, is there a way to output a 'page' as large as needed to display a large tree and to navigate it up and down (say, like a google map)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would:

- use `geometry` to get more sensible margins;
- move some branches of the tree down to conserve space;
- used squared edges to avoid branches crossing things and to reduce crowding and clutter;
- avoid putting labels so that edges are drawn through them by repositioning them slightly for greater legibility;
- use a style to simplify adding the edge labels, which allows their positions to be amended more easily and determined more consistently (and saves typing) e.g. `my label` in the example below;
- consider adding colour automatically for trees where there is a pattern e.g. all final nodes are a different colour or all left-hand nodes or whatever (but this is just to save typing and clearly a matter of preference);
- use `pdflscape` for larger trees (not needed for this one).

Here's an example:

[image: rearranged tree]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{forest}
  my label/.style={%
    if n=1{%
      edge label={node [midway,left] {#1}}
    }{%
      if n'=1{%
        edge label={node [midway,right] {#1}}
      }{%
        edge label={node [midway,below right] {#1}}
      }
    },
  },
  for tree={circle,draw, l sep=20pt},
  before typesetting nodes={
    where content={}{coordinate}{},
  },
  forked edges,
 [1,red
  [2, my label={A}
    [1,red,my label={B}
              [2,red,my label={C}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
          ]
    [1,red,my label={C}
              [2,red,my label={B}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
              ]
          [1,red,my label={D}
              [2,red,my label={B}]
              [2,red,my label={C}, tier=this]
              ]
  ]
  [, tier=this, my label={B}
  [2
    [1,red, my label={A}
              [2,red,my label={C}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
              ]
    [1,red, my label={A}
              [2,red,my label={C}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
          ]
          [1,red,my label={A}
              [2,red,my label={C}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
          ]
  ]]
      [2, my label={C}
    [1,red,my label={A}
              [2,red,my label={B}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
          ]
    [1,red,my label={B}
              [2,red,my label={A}]
              [2,red,my label={D}]
          ]
          [1,red,my label={D}
              [2,red,my label={A}]
              [2,red,my label={B}, tier=this]
              ]
  ]
  [, tier=this, my label={D}
  [2
    [1,red,my label={A}
            [2,red,my label={B}]
            [2,red,my label={C}]
            ]
    [1,red,my label={B}
            [2,red,my label={A}]
            [2,red,my label={C}]
            ]
        [1,red,my label={C}
            [2,red,my label={A}]
            [2,red,my label={B}]
            ]
    ]]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I had hoped for as an alternative to my answer. +1.

Comment: @hbaderts Looks like the only votes for our answers are from us, then ;).

Comment: @cfr Wow! Also great. This Geometry package gives a lot of control, though a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

As your tree is very wide, and not too high, one possibility would be to place it on a landscape page. The [*pdflscape*](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape?lang=de) package with its `landscape` environment creates a new page in landscape mode, which doesn't mess up your header and is even displayed correctly in the PDF viewer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % Only for creating example text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]    % Example text

\begin{landscape}
\begin{forest}
    ...
\end{forest}
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[5-7]    % Example text

\end{document}
```

[image: Result with landscape mode]

Of course, this solution will fail for *very* large forests. If that is the case, shrinking the whole forest (including text!) to fit the page might be an idea. An easy way is to use the [*adjustbox*](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox?lang=de) package, which allows you to scale any content to the desired size, e.g. by defining the width to be exactly  the `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{forest}
    ...
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result with adjustbox]

Of course, redesigning the forest to fit to your page *without* rescaling would be better, as you probably don't want to have many different, small font sizes in your document. Maybe a *forest*-expert can shed light on ways to redesign the forest in such a way.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Never heard of the latter package.