# Latex Forest goes beyond page borders?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am having an issue when using the package forest in latex to draw a hierarchical tree as follows:

```
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      l sep=1cm,
      s sep=0.1cm,
      minimum height=0.8cm,
      minimum width=2cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      font=\sffamily,
      edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
      edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
      }{}
    }
    [Anomaly Detection
    [Supervised Anomaly\\Detection
      [Support Vector\\Machine]
      [Bayesian\\Network]
      [Neural\\Networks
        [Deep\\Learning
          [AutoEncoders]
          [LSTM]
          [GRU]
        ]
      ]
      [Rule-based]
    ]
    [Statistical\\Anomaly\\Detection
      [Mixture\\Models]
      [Signal\\Processing\\Techniques]
      [Principal\\Component\\Analysis]
    ]
    [Information\\Theory
      [Correlation\\Analysis]
    ]
    [Clustering-based
      [Regular\\Clustering]
      [Co-clustering]
    ]
      ]
  \end{forest}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not what I was expecting:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try `adjustbox`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your forest in the `adjustbox` package. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329769/forest-trees-fitting-on-page) asks something similar.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

...

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
      l sep=1cm,
      s sep=0.1cm,
      minimum height=0.8cm,
      minimum width=2cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      font=\sffamily,
      edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
      edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
      }{}
    }
    [Anomaly Detection
    [Supervised Anomaly\\Detection
      [Support Vector\\Machine]
      [Bayesian\\Network]
      [Neural\\Networks
        [Deep\\Learning
          [AutoEncoders]
          [LSTM]
          [GRU]
        ]
      ]
      [Rule-based]
    ]
    [Statistical\\Anomaly\\Detection
      [Mixture\\Models]
      [Signal\\Processing\\Techniques]
      [Principal\\Component\\Analysis]
    ]
    [Information\\Theory
      [Correlation\\Analysis]
    ]
    [Clustering-based
      [Regular\\Clustering]
      [Co-clustering]
    ]
      ]
  \end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply it worked like a charm!

Comment: Consider up-voting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

i would consider possibility of the horizontal grow of tree, use `\small` font size and *not* use of an `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
      align=left,
      edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
    anchor = west,
      font = \small\sffamily\linespread{.84}\selectfont,
      forked edge,          % for forked edge
             grow = east,
            s sep = 0mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
         tier/.option=level
            }
[Anomaly\\ Detection
    [Supervised\\ Anomaly\\Detection
      [Support\\ Vector\\Machine]
      [Bayesian\\Network]
      [Neural\\Networks
        [Deep\\Learning
          [AutoEncoders]
          [LSTM]
          [GRU]
        ]
      ]
      [Rule-based]
    ]
    [Statistical\\Anomaly\\Detection
      [Mixture\\Models]
      [Signal\\Processing\\Techniques]
      [Principal\\Component\\Analysis]
    ]
    [Information\\Theory
      [Correlation\\Analysis]
    ]
    [Clustering\\ based
      [Regular\\Clustering]
      [Co-clustering]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout (text borders))

Comment: Congratulations on the 100k